# Capture json from an http response

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "./src/background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

In my background script, I have the following code:

```
console.log('I am here');
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
    console.log(request, sender, response);
});
```

When I load a page, I would expect the `console.log` inside of the listener to fire, but nothing happens. Though I do get the output `I am here`.

What I am trying to do is capture a response from a URL which contains json. I then want to get specific data from the json and send it to my server.

Maybe using `chrome.extension.onRequest` isn't the best way to do this. What should I be doing?

Comment: That's for messages sent via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. I don't understand what "URL which contains json" is, and how/where the URL request initiated.

Comment: Your code appears to have nothing to do with what your question is titled, nor is there anything which explains why you would expect your listener to fire. Please [edit] the question to be more clear as to what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Answer (score 0):

`onRequest` is deprecated, instead try using [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).

Use `onMessage` like so:
`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function callback)`

> Fired when a message is sent from either an extension process (by runtime.sendMessage) or a content script (by tabs.sendMessage).

`callback` is as follows:

`function(any message, MessageSender sender, function sendResponse) {...};`

More info can be found on the developer.chrome.com website:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage

Comment: Using that instead doesn't work. I still get the same affect

Comment: You need to call [`sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) also.

Comment: And `onMessage` is deprecated too. You need [`runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage). I will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, so using this update how do I capture network data from pages?

Comment: There is no API to capture incoming network traffic in the background page. You can capture headers. Or you can spoof XMLHttpRequest inside a [page-level script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) inserted from a content script. I think I've seen a couple of answers here.